# go back to first fragment when press back

Tags: java, android

When I am in Fragment 5, for example, and I press the back button, the application comes out. What I want is when I press the Back button, I open Fragment No. 1. How can i do that?

**I have tried many codes but it is not working, like**

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
 for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
    fm.popBackStack();
}
```

**and**

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Here is my fragment code in MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // make new object and find the view "BottomNavigationView"
    BottomNavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    // To make the first fragment shows when the app start.
    // We will ignore the "activity_main" and we will make new activity(fragment) called "fragment_home"
    // and we will add all views we want to display them on it.
    // (fragment_layout) it is a fragment have id was defined in "activity_main"
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_layout,
            new HomeFragment()).commit();
    // make Listener to call the fragments on buttons
    // to start new fragment
    navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                // first fragment "home"
                case R.id.home_item:
                    selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                // second fragment "videos"
                case R.id.videos_item:
                    selectedFragment = new VideosFragment();
                    break;
                // third fragment "ebadat"
                case R.id.ebadat_item:
                    selectedFragment = new EbadatFragment();
                    break;
                // fourth fragment "images"
                case R.id.images_item:
                    selectedFragment = new ImagesFragment();
                    break;
                // fifth fragment "more"
                case R.id.settings_item:
                    selectedFragment = new MoreFragment();
                    break;
            }
            assert selectedFragment != null;
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_layout, selectedFragment).commit();
            return true;
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to implement the onBackPressed Method in your Fragment.

1. create an interface with the name IOnBackPressed:
   click package -> new Java Class -> and choose interface in Kind -> OK
   your interface should look like this:

   ```
    public interface IOnBackPressed {
    boolean onBackPressed();
    }
   ```
2. after that you open your MainActivity and add this:

   ```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //super.onBackPressed(); delete this line
        // and start your fragment:

        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (!(fragment instanceof IOnBackPressed) || !((IOnBackPressed) fragment).onBackPressed()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
   ```
3. you implement this to your Fragment:

   ```
    public class Profil_Fragment extends Fragment implements IOnBackPressed
   ```

   and add this to the Fragment:

   ```
     @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        //do what you want
        NextFragment nextFrag= new NextFragment();
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFrag, "findThisFragment")
         .addToBackStack(null)
         .commit();

         return true;
    }
   ```

Comment: Great, it works really well and it actually does refer to the desired fragment. But when I press back again to exit the app it returns again to the last fragment.

Comment: Like when I in fragment no.5 and press back it is back to frame no.1, but when I press back again to exit it is return to frame no.5 again

Comment: Just add the onBackPressed Method to your first fragment and only return true

Answer (score 1):

Try adding transaction.addToBackStack(tag);

For example:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, selectedFragment);
ft.addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();
```

That will add your fragments to the backstack so the back button can work appropriately.

Comment: it is back to last activity, i want to back to first Activity

Answer (score 1):

Add the onBackPressed Method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed(); delete this line 
    // and start your fragment:

    NextFragment nextFrag= new NextFragment();
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.Layout_container, nextFrag, "findThisFragment")
         .addToBackStack(null)
         .commit();
}
```

Comment: In MainActivity ?

Comment: In your fragments

Comment: when I add this code ether in onCreate or outside it, it gives me an error in "@Override"

Comment: you cant write on method into an other Method. You have to write it in the class. Also you have to implement the obBackPressed Method with Alt + Enter.

Comment: Fragment lifecycle do not have onBackPressed()

Comment: I posted a new answer!

Answer (score 0):

Add backstack and tag (you can use fragment name like "HomeFragment") for replacing fragment.

```
replace(fragmentId, fragment, fragmentName).addToBackStack(fragmentName)
```

And pop fragment like this

```
popBackStack(fragmentName,0)
```

Comment: You can use like this HomeFragment::class.java.simpleName instead of fragmentName
and fragment is HomeFragment() 
fragmenId is R.id.fragment_layout

Comment: give me this error "Required type:
String

Provided:
Class
<com.picsapp.moamenapp.Fragment.HomeFragment>" when use HomeFragment.cllass

Comment: use HomeFragment::class.java.simpleName
or VideosFragment::class.java.simpleName etc.